# Restore cloud run after delete project from firebase ->restore project from GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

Few days ago, I've deleted a project from firebase (we were not using it anymore)
But it also removed the GCP project.

I managed to restore it, activate the billing again.

Now, when I try to deploy a runner, it takes few minutes before saying in the revision details:
Project not found. Resource readiness deadline exceeded.

Demo is comming soon, I would very appreciate your help :)

Thank you!

I've reactivated billing

Checked if the project was found on the gcloud cli

Tryied to push a new artifact using docker push (worked)

I've even tryied to put the Cloud run admin role to the service-[ID]@serverless-robot-prod.iam.gserviceaccount.com